# How do I set credit card limits for Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just signed-up for **Amazon EC2**, for a micro instance server.
Does anyone know how I can set-up limits on data usage and/or the monthly amount that can be charged to my Credit Card?

Comment: You can use a low-limit single use card.

Comment: Duplicate of http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/20534/how-to-set-credit-card-limits-for-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 4):

Amazon [does not currently (Feb 2011) provide the functionality](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=222519𶔷) to place a cap or limit on your bill.

There is a third party company that provides this service for you called [AWS Balance Monitor](http://www.codewall.com/awsmonitor/)